# multiple http get request node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

This is what my code looks like for a single http get request. What I want to do is call two more http get request and store their results so I can render appropriately. Can anyone please suggests how I can achieve it? Thanks

```
router.get('/get_all_posts', function(req, res){
        var body ='';

        var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            path: '/some_endpoint',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        };


        var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
            response.setEncoding('utf8');

            response.on('data', function (data_chunk) {
                body += data_chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function () {

                if(response) {
                    res.render("something");
                }
                else
                {
                    res.render('error', {error: {status:400,stack:body}});
                }

            });
        });
        request.end();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
async.map([options1, options2, options3], reqCall, function(err, results){
            if ( err){
                // do something
            } else {
                   results[0]//first call
                   results[1]//second call
                   results[2] //third call
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be making http request. Whatever code you have for `/some_endpoint` turn it into a function, and then call that function inside router for both `/some_endpoint` and `/get_all_posts`.

Hope it helps.